# POST RequestBody e Multipart no retrofit2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Como enviar uma imagem e o jsonObject para o webservice em uma única requisição no retrofit2?

Interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("url")
Call<Mensagens> setChatMessage(@HeaderMap Map<String,String> headers, @Body RequestBody params, @Part MultipartBody.Part img);
```

Class

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), params.toString());
                RequestBody reqFileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part mPart1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","file",reqFileBody);
                service = new RetrofitConfig().getServices().setChatMessage(headers, body, mPart1);
```

Erro

```
@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #2)
```

Comment: Melhor enviar a imagem como um atributo do próprio objeto.

Comment: Caso você possa da uma olhada no próprio stack tem um link muito bom que pode ajudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2/56412584